# What is PHP syntax to put individual array contents into a string variable?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am building a string variable called $order_sql. It is basically like this:

**`$order_sql = "INSERT INTO TEMPTABLE Cust_no, Order_no VALUES ('10', '5')";` 
**
The problem I am having is that the Cust_no and Order_no are stored in an associative array called $order, so I am trying to do the following:

**`"... VALUES ($order ['Customer No'], $order ['Order No'])"` 
**
but I do not get the 10 and 5, but this:
**`"... VALUES (Array['Customer No'], Array['Order No'])"` 
**
However if I assign the array values to variables first, such as
**`$CustNo = $order ['Customer No']; $OrderNo = $order ['Order No'];`
**
and then use these variables
**`"... VALUES (\'$CustNo\', \'$OrderNo\' )";` 
**
I get the desired result:
**`"... VALUES ('10', '5')";`
**
This seems similar the Prepared Statements information in post [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement)
but I am not using MySQL. The SQL sting I am preparing is sent via a SOAP API call, which is then executed within that to actually run the SQL on the database.